# ImageView onImageChangedListener Android

Tags: android, image, imageview, actionlistener

Is there an onImageChangedListener() on a ImageView?

I need the event when the image is changed from the ImageView.

Comment: The image is changed onButtonClick, choosing it from Camera or SDCard.

Comment: I mean exactly how are you changing the image?  setImageBitmap?  setImageDrawable?  Other?

Comment: there is not, because the change of image comes from the code, which means that you know when it changes.

Comment: @Simon I am using setImageBitmap() or setImageResource(), depends If I am taking it from SDCard or using the R.id.default_image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the imageview code in grepcode. You don't know when it is changed or redrawn. It is because after you setImageDrawable(), imageview will invalidate. At this time, the image IS NOT CHANGED correctly until ondraw is called.

Anyway, why do you want to know the onimagechangedlistener?

Answer (score 25):

There is no default listener in Android .. but we can create the imagechange listiner .. copy the class and instead of using ImageView use MyImageView..

```
 public class MyImageView extends ImageView {

        private OnImageChangeListiner onImageChangeListiner;


        public MyImageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {         
            super(context, attributeSet); 
        }


        public void setImageChangeListiner(
                OnImageChangeListiner onImageChangeListiner) {
            this.onImageChangeListiner = onImageChangeListiner;
        }

        @Override
        public void setBackgroundResource(int resid) {
            super.setBackgroundResource(resid);
            if (onImageChangeListiner != null)
                onImageChangeListiner.imageChangedinView(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background) {
            super.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
            if (onImageChangeListiner != null)
                onImageChangeListiner.imageChangedinView(this);
        }


        public static interface OnImageChangeListiner {
            public void imageChangedinView(ImageView mImageView);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what should I import for "OnImageChangeListiner cannot be resolved to a type" ?

Comment: copy this class in any package ... import packagename.MyImageView;

Comment: You should implement the interface in your activity and override imageChangedInView().  `extends Activity implements OnImageChangeListiner`

Comment: yaaa implements MyImageView.OnImageChangeListiner

Comment: Don't forget to add this constructor or it may crash when inflating view from XML: `public mImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) { super(context, attributeSet); }`

Comment: If you get "Custom view MyImageView is not using the 2- or 3-argument View constructors; XML attributes will not work" have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13797457

Comment: You'll want to override setImageBitmap in a manner similar to what Sandy09 mentioned if you're using it to change the image.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load the image from network and check change in imageview you can use imageView.isAttachedToWindow(). I have tried downloading the image from network and disabled the progressbar after image downloaded and attached to window.
Use,

```
         if(imageView.isAttachedToWindow()){ 
            //your code here
          }
```