# .java not using the 2- or 3-argument View constructors; XML attributes will not work

Tags: android, eclipse

i'm newbie i have problem creating game

execute process

activity_main.xml -> MainActivity.java -> GameLoop.java -> action.xml (error) -> CustomView.java

```
Custom view CustomView is not using the 2- or 3-argument View constructors; XML attributes will not work
```

I don't understand......

Comment: Do not edit a question because you solved it already.. rather post your solution.

Comment: Don't suggest edits to other people's answers either.  Post your own answer.

Answer (score 60):

You need to override the other 2 constructors of View in CustomView:

```
public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    //do stuff that was in your original constructor...
}
```

Comment: changed this code
action.xml error now.Study.androidproject.CustomView failed to instantiate.
java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: The following classes could not be instantiated:
- now.Study.androidproject.CustomView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse

Comment: err... sorry i left a call to init() in the init function, probably a stack overflow error, corrected now

Comment: Where should I add this?

Comment: The 2nd constructor calls init twice.

Answer (score 11):

You need to implement these constructors also:

```
//Constructor that is called when inflating a view from XML.
View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)

//Perform inflation from XML and apply a class-specific base style.
View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends how You creating Your custom view and how You gonna use it
.
Not all 3 constructors really necessary.
If You create the view with attributes xml file,  but won't use defstyle, its enough to call

```
public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs);
    //Your code
}
```

if You not using attributes and defstlye /i saw examples for this/ You happy to call only

```
public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    //Your code
}
```

and if You want use defstyle and attributes too

```
public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs);
    //Yourcode
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone works with Kotlin he/she can do that:

```
class KotlinView @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

You can find this solution and more details here: https://antonioleiva.com/custom-views-android-kotlin/