# Android dynamic Bubbles on the view

Tags: android, android-layout

Can anyone how to make dynamic bubble on the Android layout which is clickable.

My designer thought for the screen is below  [![I the image all the bubble are some set of task assigned to the user.The label of bubble changes according to the task ][1]][1]

According to my project requirement the color and radius will change as per the api response.

Can you please suggest any demo or example. I googled it but i cant find the answer for this. Please guide me to accomplish this .

Comment: There is nothing built in for this.  You'll have to do it all from scratch.  Shouldn't be too bad though-  drawing circles on a Canvas is pretty easy.  Look into how to make custom views.

Comment: @GabeSechan can you please suggest some example for this ?

Comment: You have to draw all views on canvas.

Comment: @tpa can you please provide some code snipp for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one answer is already posted, I also tried for you. Hope you get some help from here too :

```
public class BubbleBackgroundDemoActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View view = new CustomView(this);
//        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(this.getWidth(),
//                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
//        view.setLayoutParams(lp);


        setContentView(view);
    }

    public class CustomView extends View {

        private Paint paint;
        int screenWidth, screenHeight;



        public CustomView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();

            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);


           screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
             screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

            // create the Paint and set its color
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
            canvas.drawCircle(200, 200, 100, paint);


            canvas.drawCircle(screenWidth-200, 200, 100, paint);

            canvas.drawCircle(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2, 300, paint);

            canvas.drawCircle(screenWidth-200, screenHeight-200, 100, paint);

            canvas.drawCircle(200, screenHeight-200, 100, paint);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: great work its works perfectly . Then my another doubt is how can i give click method on this circles, and different colors for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how customize circle created you can refere various links to create circle on canvas dynamically

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    private Paint paint;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // create the Paint and set its color        
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(200, 200, 100, paint);
    }

}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new CustomView(this));
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for this . Can you please guide me to how this implementin in project

Comment: create a custom view like CustomView create a constructor and pass parameter for position x, y and radius .

Comment: create circle by call CustomView object

Comment: @siddesh my another doubt is how can i give click method on this circles, and different colors for the same ?

Comment: http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2012/04/draw-circle-on-canvas-canvasdrawcirclet.html go through this link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132062/discussion-between-pranav-ms-and-siddhesh).