# how do you recycle the bitmap loaded from a file into an ImageView when trying to load another into it

Tags: android, bitmap, recycle

```
File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");

if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

//This works all well and good until myImage.setImageBitmap is called again (after a picture is taken and loaded in this little "post-view" ImageView rectangle which is myImage) and it runs out of memory.

Comment: Have you tried disabling image caching, or invalidate() on image view?

Comment: you can make your custom class and notify when image changes on ImageView and then recycle the bitmap . have some idea from here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622081/imageview-onimagechangedlistener-android

Answer (score 0):

I think that will helps you.

```
File imgFile = new  File("/sdcard/Images/test_image.jpg");
private Bitmap mLastUpdatedBitmap;

if(imgFile.exists()){
    if(mLastUpdatedBitmap != null && !mLastUpdatedBitmap.isRecycled()){
       mLastUpdatedBitmap.recycle();
    }
    mLastUpdatedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);
    myImage.setImageBitmap(mLastUpdatedBitmap);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap myBitmap;
if(imgFile.exists()){

     if(myBitmap!=null){
         myBitmap.recycle();
         myBitmap=null;
     }
     myBitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

Comment: I should note of importance to prevent out of memory error I needed to consider my source of the images (the camera). My image was just way too big especially considering I had another handler on a timer that was loading and sending the picture via http at the same time (when connection was available). When I setup my camera I had to set some parameters: c = Camera.open(); 
            Camera.Parameters p = c.getParameters();
            p.setJpegQuality (75);
            p.setPictureSize (640,480);
            c.setParameters(p);

Comment: @murphy what you want to know. Can you please clarify?