# Determine if view was invalidated (changed)

Tags: android, view, bitmap

How I can determine if a view was invalidated? I see that the View class has isDirty() method but it doesn't seem to work in my case.

I'm making a custom layout that can animate blurring of it's content. It extends FrameLayout. So at first the layout draws it's first child to a bitmap, and than displays the bitmap instead of actual view. Also it starts AsyncTask that creates blur animation steps.

So I need to know when the child view was changed so I can redraw the bitmap and restart AsyncTask.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622081/imageview-onimagechangedlistener-android

Comment: @KristyWelsh thank you but that doesn't cover my situation. A child view may be not only an ImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that this can be implemented using `ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener`