# show message when imageview is not empy without clicking a button

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera

I have a button to select a picture or take a picture from camera, what i want is when the imageview that i use to attached the picture *has an image on it*., show a message right away, **without clicking a button**.

What i do now is when you press on a button then it shows some hidden edittext that says "image uploaded" or something. I want to achive this but without clicking any button.
I've had tried many other options but all of them use a button.

Any samples or ideas!
Thanks in advance

```
bb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            validacionImagen();
  }
});
```

METHOD THAT VALIDATES WHETER THERE'S AN ATTACHED IMAGE:

```
     public void validacionImagen(){
    if(imageView.getDrawable()==null){
        buttonChoose.setError("Sube una fotografía");
        buttonChoose.setFocusable(true);
        buttonChoose.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        buttonChoose.requestFocus();
    }else{
        imagencargada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textoimagencargada.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonChoose.setError(null);

    }
}
```

PICTURE CODE:

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Elige una imagen"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == CAM_REQUEST){
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your current code and explain/show code of what exactly have you tried.

Comment: @KrzysztofBracha it's a button when click on it calls validacionImagen(), to show some TextView, but i want to show it without clicking a button, when the imageview has an image show those TextView right away

Comment: But when imageview can have an image? When load activity?

Comment: Once you take a picture or select a picture from the gallery. @DanielRL

Comment: Show this code too

Comment: Ready @DanielRL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're calling startActivityForResult in order to get the picture from the camera or gallery like:

```
startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Then, you can override onActivityResult to check the results from that intent.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {
        case SELECT_PICTURE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                //Manage the picture taken here with data
            } else {
                //The intent was cancelled or didn't bring any data
            }
    }
}
```

Now, if this isn't the approach you're looking for and all you want to do is to check when an ImageView has changed, you can implement a custom ImageView with a listener. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13622364/6828464)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make something like this:

```
public class ImageView extends ImageView {

    private OnImageChangeListener onImageChangeListener;

    public ImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ImageView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void setImageChangeListiner(
            OnImageChangeListener onImageChangeListener) {
        this.onImageChangeListener = onImageChangeListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackgroundResource(int resid) {
        super.setBackgroundResource(resid);
        if (onImageChangeListener != null)
            onImageChangeListener.onImageChanged(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background) {
        super.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
        if (onImageChangeListener != null)
            onImageChangeListener.onImageChanged(this);
    }


    public interface OnImageChangeListener {
        void onImageChanged(ImageView imageView);
    }

}
```

Create custom ImageView with a listener to notify when you set the image  and override some method that you use to set the image in ImageView to call the listener.

Comment: So now using this class, how can i implement it on my activity or what should i replace @Daniel RL

Comment: Show me your activity